# Mathematical logic: Predicates, formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've got universum $A = \{0,1,2\}$

Predicate:
$R^{A}=\{\{x,y\} \in A \times A \hspace{2mm} | \hspace{2mm} x \neq y \} $

Terms:

$f^A(x) = 1$

$g^A(x,y) = min(x,y)$

Constant $c^A = 2$

Valuation:

$v(x)=0, \hspace{0.5cm} v(y)=0, \hspace{0.5cm} v(z)=1$

Formulas:

1, $\forall x \forall y(R(x,y) \implies R(g(x,y),y))$

2, $\forall x \exists y(R(x,y) \implies R(g(x,y),y))$

3, $\forall x g(x,y)$

4, $(\forall x R(x,y)) \implies (\forall y R(g(x,y),y))$

5, $f(g(f(x),c))$

Now I have to choose if expression (1-5) is term or formula and determine value.

My result so far:

3, nothing

5, term, value: 1

Please what is the differences between formula 1 and 2 and 4 ? I am not sure to calculate it

Comment: Formula 2): consider the possible value $1$ for $x$. Then $R(1,y)$ is true for $0$ or $2$ as values for $y$. While $0$ does not sat the consequent [because: $R(min(1,0),0)$ is false], $2$ is ok [because: $R(min(1,2),2)$ is true]. Conclusion: for $1$ as $x$ it is true that there is a possible valur for $y$ such that... Now formula 1): for the value $1$ for $x$, for the same reason, it is not true that for all values for $y$ ...

Comment: I am sorry, interpratation constant $c$ was fill. I didn't rewrite.

Comment: Ok I understand. And can I ask how it will be in Formula 4 please ?

Comment: For 4); $\forall x R(x,0)$ is *false* because, for $0$ as value for $x$, $0 \ne 0$ is *false*. Thus, the conditional is *true*, because its antecedent is *false*